# How to handle error code 302 in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a login web-service (SOAP-based) which is based on https protocol.
While trying to run the test through jmeter, the error code 302 is coming. It's due to a certificate issue as observed when I hit the same web-service through browser.

How to handle that certificate via jmeter?

Answer (score 1):

First off, I'd like to thank the person who suggested to use JMeter proxy server to resolve the 302 error. It worked for me. Just a few suggestions and gotchas to follow and watch out for:

- This Step By Step guide will help you with setting up the proxy
  server:
  http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf
- Once the proxy server is set up, you will have to come up with
  regular expressions to match your include and exclude URL patterns.
  The following web-site proved very useful:
  http://gskinner.com/RegExr/
- This step the guide mentions but I just thought to mention it here
  since it's easy to overlook: when you start recording navigation,
  keep an eye on the JMeter's Recording Controller that's under
  ThreadGroup. As you navigate through your pages, corresponding
  samplers should start appearing under it. If no samplers are created
  then chances are your include URL pattern doesn't pick them up.

========================================================================

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try recording the request using jmeter proxy server and retry the same